# Android sharing intent with google maps location and URL Shortener API

Tags: android, google-maps, url, google-url-shortener

I am trying to share a location with latitude and longitude as;

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" + latLngMaps.latitude + "," + latLngMaps.longitude;
```

Using these lines of code:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                String ShareSub = pharmacyName + "\n" + pharmacyAddress;
                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, ShareSub + "\n" + shortURL);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share With?"));
```

What I want to do is:

[image: Image taken from Whatsapp Windows app]

I am using URL shortener api and converting the `"http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" + latLngMaps.latitude + "," + latLngMaps.longitude;` to goo.gl/xxxxx

It becomes like this [image: Shared from my app]

Is it possible to get that first Image's view when I share my map on Whatsapp?

If it is not, How can I shorten my link as goo.gl/maps/xxxx not goo.gl/xxxx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Google static Maps API which returns a map as an Image which you can share through intent.You can also customize static maps API like you can set marker location, set zoom level.

```
Url
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Australia&size=640x400&style=element:labels|visibility:off&style=element:geometry.stroke|visibility:off&style=feature:landscape|element:geometry|saturation:-100&style=feature:water|saturation:-100|invert_lightness:true&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

You can also use the lighter version of google map using google map options. it is also displayed as an Image. which can be clicked and also has google map customization.

[visit my website for learnning Kotlin and Android - Developine](http://developine.com/)

Comment: Can I make that image clickable? For instance, think that I shared that image on whatsapp, if the reciever user clicks the image he/she must go to the link that I want to put inside image.You can think it as "Href"

Comment: i have updated answer. please check. You can use google map options. google it and get the idea of what i am talking about.