# Send share live location intent from 3rd party app to Whatsapp

Tags: android, android-intent

With the new WhatsApp feature which is Sharing Live Location, I am wondering if there is any way to send an intent to the WhatsApp app from my Android app. I am aware of an existing method provided which is sending intent, but it’s only to accommodate sending some texts.

Comment: May this link helps you [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47522022/android-sharing-intent-with-google-maps-location-and-url-shortener-api)

Comment: no answers yet? i was wondering the same